# Remove a text box, python

Tags: python, textbox

Is there a way to use Python to remove a text box from a file say on MS Word and Excel?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Your question is not really well-specified, but I'm going to have to say that in the general case the answer is probably no.  If you have some much more specific use case, you might want to tell us about it.

Comment: Yes, Sorry for not being more elaborate. I was just playing around with a blank word document and added a test box and wondered to myself, if there is some python syntax out there to control it....most specifically, add one or remove one....

Comment: It probably depends more upon the version of Word you're using; newer versions use a gzipped XML format, if I recall correctly, and you might be able to easily manipulate that.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the MS Word API
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/16/python-and-microsoft-office-using-pywin32/